# access a directory/folder with "no name"(a white space) in C#

Tags: c#, filepath

how can i access a directory/folder with "no name"(a white space) in C#.
i have tried

```
string currentDir = "G:\\";
string targetDir = currentDir + "\\" + " " + "\\";
now targetDir === "G:\\ \\";
```

but NO, when i use targetDir to get file list in "G:\ \" it just show me files in "G:\" not "G:\ \"

thanks

[Image Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52038693/NoNameFolder.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, the only way I was able to emulate this was to use ALT + 0160 to make a blank space folder (this is actually known as the non-breaking space and in html code, it's `&#0160;` or `&nbsp;`).

For this character, you can get the files in the blank space folder like below by utilizing *System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode*:

```
testDir1 = currentDir + "\\" + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@"&nbsp;") + "\\";
```

or

```
testDir1 = currentDir + "\\" + System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@"&#0160;") + "\\";
```

Which got me the file that was in the blank folder.
[image: Grabbing files from blank space folder]

See if it works for you, if it doesn't, then your character is some other strange character that you will have to find out exactly what it is before you can even continue.

Comment: ok this looks promising, i'll get back to you once i've tried this. thanks

Comment: Thank you Very much both option work. and thanks to everybody else too!!

Comment: The _non-breaking space_ character can also be achieved by converting the character code to a char like so: `(char)160` - The key, however, seems to be the trailing backslash. Without it, I just get the files of the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the character might not actually be a whitespace. Eg. if I rename a folder by holding down alt and typing ascii code 00160, it results in a blank folder name on my machine.

Comment: really i didnt know about that, so is there anyways to know what character it is and most importantly is there a way i can navigate to it in C# that is

Comment: @NaGaaJaBesa Try this to see the Unicode code of the file: var lst = Directory.GetDirectories(@"G:\", "?").Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p) + "|" + ((int)Path.GetFileName(p)[0]).ToString("X4")).ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

Following "[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions)" space character is not supported as ending in file or directory name, the other words is not supported as name as well.

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

Comment: it is not me who created the folder, its a virus that creates it and move all your files on your flash to that folder and hides it. now all i want to do is move back all the files inside that folder to the root of the flash.
fyi im doing this now manually but i want to automate it because a lot of people are coming to me with this problem and i have to do it again and again and again.

Comment: @NaGaa that explains a lot, Windows doesn't normally let you create folders such as this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the folders in the current path via `FileInfo` and run a loop on the array retrieved, searching for a folder that it's name has 1 char in it and is not an ordinary char. Yes, it won't work dynamically since on some PC's a specific char is considered ordinary and on a different one it isn't, but that's what comes to my mind and if the script is for your personal use, I see no reason not to use this workaround :)